# Open rate for each link

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I need to validate the open rate of each link that has a journey, I tried by sql query with this code.

```
select
c.subscriberKey as 'ContactID',
ja.ActivityName as 'EmailName',
c.EventDate as 'ClickDate',
c.LinkName as 'LinkName'
from [_click] as c
join [_JourneyActivity] as ja 
on c.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = ja.JourneyActivityObjectID
join [_Journey] as j
on ja.VersionID = j.VersionID
where ja.ActivityType in ('316729')
and j.JourneyName = 'Journey WH Colombia 2023'
```

Open rate for each link

I need to validate the open rate of each link that has a journey, I tried by sql query with this code.

It doesn't give any result, my data extension is configured as follows
ContactID - number
EmailName-text 100
ClickDate-date
LinkName-text 254

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this:

```SQL
select
c.subscriberKey as ContactID,
ja.ActivityName as EmailName,
c.EventDate as ClickDate,
c.LinkName as LinkName
from [_click] as c
join [_JourneyActivity] as ja 
on c.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = ja.JourneyActivityObjectID
join [_Journey] as j
on ja.VersionID = j.VersionID
where ja.ActivityType = 'EMAILV2'
and j.JourneyName = 'Journey WH Colombia 2023'
```

ActivityType = 'EMAILV2' is for email send activity.

And for the targeted data extension, I would put the **text** data type for ContactID field since if the contacts came from Salesforce CRM then their IDs would be combined with numbers and alphabet characters.

You may want to change "ContactID" field name to SubscriberKey or ContactKey to avoid confusing with ContactID in Marketing Cloud concept.

> The Contact ID is a number Salesforce uses to uniquely identify a contact on the backend.

Reference: [Contact Keys, Contact IDs, and Subscriber Keys](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-contact-management/understand-contacts-and-contact-model-relationships#:%7E:text=Marketing%20Cloud%20will%20process%20the,a%20contact%20on%20the%20backend.)